# Is there a way to sync my personal files to my Nook Color & G2 phone?

Tags: sync, ebook-reader, htc-desire-z, cloud, nook-color

- I just got a Nook Color which runs on Android.
- I also have an Android G2 phone with the Nook app running on it.
- If I purchase a book from Barnes & Nobles I see the book online in my "My NOOK Library" at the Barnes & Nobles web site.
- I can also read such books on my Nook Color & G2 phone (this is great).

The problem is that I also have PDF documents  that I would like to sync between both the Nook Color & G2 phone.

I was hoping that the Barnes & Nobles "My NOOK Library" at the web site in the cloud would allow me to upload my personal PDFs so that they could sync to my phone and Nook.

Does anyone know:

- If Barnes & Nobles currently supports this?
- If not, will they support it?
- If not, any ideas how I could accomplish this (other than doing it manually which I currently do)?

Comment: If it's any consolation, it's the same situation with Kindle. Anything from the Kindle bookstore is available to the apps on every device and syncs reading positions, but PDFs, DOCs, texts, pictures are only on the device you put them on (even if you used Amazon's Whispernet to deliver them to that device).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that functionality works yet.  I have tried to sideload PDFs and plain .txt files and they don't register in "My Library" or under "My Files" and obviously they don't sync between my devices.  I also can't find a web interface for loading non-nook files.

I did a little searching around a couple months ago and I found a few unsubstantiated forum posts that claim that it's planned functionality but the Android app currently only supports sideloaded ePub files.

> If not, any ideas how I could
>   accomplish this (other than doing it
>   manually which I currently do)?

I'd say your best bet right now is to do this outside the Nook app.  Sideload ([or wait till Jan](http://www.engadget.com/2010/12/14/nook-color-getting-android-2-2-and-market-in-january-current-ha/) for the Market) a PDF reader and [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTExNDUyMTkyOQ?src=global0) or [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/referral?rf=cic2fwnnpgs8h) onto your Nook Color to keep your PDFs synced and accessable.

**For full disclosure: those Dropbox and SugarSync links are my referral links so if you don't already have them and you use those links both you and I get some free extra storage* ;o)

Comment: I was able to access my dropbox account via the web browser but it would be nice to have the actual drop box Android app installed. I hope Barnes & Nobles offers this in it's custom app store when it comes out in January.

Comment: Does the Nook allow you to sideload apps?  You can download the Dropbox app directly from the dropbox site.  There's a link at the bottom for "Mobile" then from there choose "Android"...

Comment: not sure, I'll have to look into it. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

**[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com)** will allow you to add pdfs to your notebooks. Evernote is available for the NC as well as for Android and iOS. Once the pdf is in a notebook, it'll sync via Evernote.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you cannot achieve this on built-in **Nook app**. Fortunately, you are using two android
devices since there are many solutions for reading on android devices.

Install **Moon + reader under the assistance of Dropbox** on your android phone and Nook color. 
You can also keep the same reading progress in this method. 
[guide](http://www.epubor.com/sync-kindle-furthest-page-read-on-computers-and-ios-android-devices.html#3)